# Is there a Sublime Text Syntax for Flex and Bison?

Tags: sublimetext2, bison, yacc, lex, sublimetext3

I'm looking for a syntax in Sublime Text that highlights my Flex and Bison files (or lex/yacc) in a way that makes them readable... Sublime Text automatically chooses Lisp for Flex files, but that doesn't do the trick all that well. Any suggestions to try another syntax? Or is there a plugin somewhere that's useful (haven't found anything so far)?.

Comment: This guy, https://github.com/Jackneill/sublime-text-packages/tree/master/Packages, seems to have packages for both Bison and Flex.  I have not tried them myself.

Comment: The Flex is actually Adobe Flex, but Bison may be interesting to add. Thx.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't found one built specifically for Sublime, but I've found one for TextMate, which Sublime is compatible with.

Therefore, for Flex highlight, all you need to do is git clone the [TextMate's syntax files](https://github.com/textmate/lex-flex.tmbundle) to your Packages folder.

Regarding Bison, I've found a syntax for TextMate, but it didn't work very well for me. The one [Vaklarados posted](http://code.artyom-smirnov.info/sublimetext2-packages/overview) worked nicer with my source files.

Comment: That plugin is exactly what I need! Thank you!  However the the one Vlakarados posted is not yacc-bison.  Still on the lookout for that. May end up writing one soon.

Comment: Hello, I `git clone`d this repository in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\` and ST3 still doesn't know the flex syntax, even after a restart. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @Arno I had the same problem. One of the files in the git repository has a `:` in it, so it doesn't clone correctly on Windows. You'll have to download the `Syntaxes/Lex:Flex.tmLanguage` file manually (and remove the `:` from the name) and put it in the folder, and it should work then.

Answer (score 3):

The one thalesmello posted works well for Flex.  For Bison, I've found this one - it's pretty minimal but it's a start:

https://github.com/Jackneill/sublime-text-packages/tree/master/Packages/Bison

Please let me know if you find something better!

edit: I take it back - the Flex one highlights start states & C/C++ code in pink and it looks quite terrible. For basic lex files it looks okay, but it needs work. :)

edit again: as sonu kumar pointed out, the project has been removed from github.  For an alternative you could try the built-in OCamlyacc highlighting (pretty decent), or another alternative: https://bitbucket.org/artyom_smirnov/sublime-text-bison-highlighter (needs some work)

I'm using Sublime a lot more & do a fair bit of work in Flex/Bison, so I might get around to writing one... one day. :D

Comment: Ahh balls, looks like the project was deleted... :( I'll have to dig around for a clone.

Comment: @sonukumar Can't find a clone - the built-in OCamlyacc one looks pretty decent though, and there's another one here: https://bitbucket.org/artyom_smirnov/sublime-text-bison-highlighter/src/2c46905909f4ae77ba02504122dffb3052ec8171/Bison.tmLanguage?at=master but it's not as good as the OCamlyacc one.

Comment: Thanks I installed using package manager .So there is no problem .

Comment: Do we have any solution for lex/flex on  windows? Installation  works on linux system (Ubuntu) but failed on windows with error  `file name invalid` .

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there are:

- [Flex](https://github.com/itsgg/Flex-Sublimetext)
- [Bison](http://code.artyom-smirnov.info/sublimetext2-packages)

It's not so hard to write your own packages for non-typical languages. Just browse the source of other language syntax files and copy-paste-change what you need. Also raises your regex skills to a better level.

Comment: I guess I'll have to write them my own as Flex is Adobe Flex and Bison is Binary JSON...

Comment: Sorry, looks like I didn't understand you right on this one, I was pretty sure after you replied to the comment above you were actually talking about Adobe :)

Comment: Indeed, kind of confusing of me.

Comment: I know this is an old answer. But your answer links are 404.

Answer (score 2):

Install Package Control for Sublime Text.

I found this there: 
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Bison

Do try it, I found it good enough for my use.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/m-happy/Packages/blob/master/Flex/Flex.sublime-syntax

You can add this file to your sublime package.