# How to make sublime text 3 mark syntax of lex on windows

Tags: syntax, sublimetext3, lex

***i am trying to mark lex syntax in sublime text 3***

i downloaded from github package that marks the syntax of lex file and put it on

***Sublime Text 3\Packages***

and then i restart sublime text 3 and nothing has changed

```
%{

    #include <string.h>

%}
```

This code is fully white also after installing the package from github(the color doesn't change)

the git i cloned is- https://github.com/textmate/lex-flex.tmbundle

Comment: you should make sure the file is viewed with the right syntax in `View -> Syntax`, then close and reopen the file

Comment: There is not Lex syntax in View -> Syntax on sublime text 3

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19217871/10530671), for lexer syntax texmate syntax files can be used with SublimeText.

To mark lex syntax in sublime text 3:

- clone git repository into `packages/User`: https://github.com/textmate/lex-flex.tmbundle
- open a lexer file
- set lexer syntax in `View -> Syntax -> User > Lex/Flex`

Comment: I dont find User in Syntax (this is for windows 10?)

Comment: your syntax might not be installed correctly, then. Can you confirm the syntax is installed: `Packages/User/lex-flex.tmbundle/Syntaxes/Lex:Flex.tmLanguage`?

Comment: i got file in this path named Lex the file name change something?

Comment: your OS might be hiding the file extension. You should name it `LexFlex.tmLanguage`

Comment: I did it and i still cant see User after i pressed Syntax

Comment: I am not on Windows so I cannot look into it any further, thouh it is claimed to work on Windows. It should appear on Syntax/User for windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`
2. Clone git repository https://github.com/textmate/lex-flex.tmbundle
3. In Sublimetext 3 open `View -> Syntax -> Lex/Flex`

In step 1, AppData folder maybe hidden, so you can either copy the path from above and replace your username; or from `folder > view > [tick] hidden item`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to

   ```
   C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
   ```
2. ```
   Clone git repository `https://github.com/textmate/lex-flex.tmbundle
   ```
3. Go to

   ```
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/textmate/lex-flex.tmbundle/master/Syntaxes/Lex%3AFlex.tmLanguage
   ```

   and **copy all**
4. Create a new file named `LexFlex.tmLanguage` in:

   ```
   C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\lex-flex.tmbundle\Syntaxes
   ```

   and paste what you copied in it.
5. Save.

Now you will see lex/flex in syntax.